# Filter identical or similar column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like following:

```
ID | Title
_____________________
1  | Samurai
2  | Airplane
3  | Samurai (2nd edition)
4  | The Deer Hunter
5  | Samurai
6  | Pan's Labyrinth
7  | Airplane 2010
```

I need to only keep the records that have identical or similar records. The expected outcome for the above table is following:

```
ID | Title
_____________________
1  | Samurai
2  | Airplane
3  | Samurai (2nd edition)
5  | Samurai
7  | Airplane 2010
```

Can this be achieved in one or at least two queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to do a self join on the condition that the title from the first table is a substring of the title in the second table, or vice-versa:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.Title
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON (t1.Title LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.Title, '%') OR
       t2.Title LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.Title, '%')) AND
       t1.ID <> t2.ID
ORDER BY
    t1.ID;
```

[image]

### Demo

Selecting with `DISTINCT` is necessary here because a given pair of matching records would appear twice in the result set.  Appreciate that this works, because, for example, `Samurai`, one title, appears as a portion of the title `Samurai (2nd edition)`.  Similar logic applies to the other matches.

Edit based on Gordon's comment:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Title
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE (t1.Title LIKE CONCAT('%', t2.Title, '%') OR
                     t2.Title LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.Title, '%')) AND
                    t1.ID <> t2.ID)
ORDER BY
    t1.ID;
```

### Demo

Comment: `EXISTS` is a better alternative because you don't need to remove duplicates afterwards.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I updated my answer, with your answer.  `EXISTS` probably would be more efficient than join, in addition to what you already mentioned, because MySQL would not have to comb the entire table, for each record on the left side.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, Title
from table
group by Title
```

GROUP BY documentation https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp